# Restrict access to account in test class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Is it possible to create user with some special permissions to provide `catch` section coverage
Let's say we have method to be tested (only SOQL)

```
SELECT id
FROM Account
WHERE recordType.DeveloperName  in :recordTypes
    AND id = :accountId 
WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
LIMIT 1
```

I just want to invoke this class using Test.runAs() but seems like when it comes to Account there is not possible to restrict access to Account object. Any ideas? Catch section looks like

```
catch(Exception e) {
    CustomLogger.log(e.getMessage());
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Updated: I want my class to throw exception like `Insufficient permissions` during calling it from test class inside Test.runAs(testUser)

Comment: You should edit your post to include the full test class and the class that's being tested so we can better contextualize the problem.

Comment: the one and only thing i need is to know is it possible to restrict access to standard Account object during creating test user in test class. I want my class to throw exception like `Insufficient permissions`

Comment: Ah I see. I think you'd have to create a profile that specifically doesn't have Account access if you don't have one already and make sure to assign that profile to your Test User. I don't think there's a way to modify a user's permissions like that in the context of a test class.